# Where to find real-world, large matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am experimenting with some C/C#/C++ code on matrix multiplication.  Does anyone know where I could find real-world matrices - something with more than 1000 elements?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of sparse matrices available on [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/). There is an IO function available on the website for a number of different programming languages.

Comment: Very nice resource!

Comment: Not a great use of my tax dollars, but better than some :-)

Answer (score 1):

LAPACK comes with it's own "test matrix generator library", you can try to see what it does. You can also try and roll your own, say by generating a large [DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) matrix and showing the you can retrieve the original signal